# jmeter variable value altered by multiple thread

Tags: jmeter

**My Test plan**

[image]

**"Header"** is a variable that undergoes some processing and gets fed into the HTTP Request.
I have no problem running this test when the number of thread is 1, but when **the number of thread is >1,** the variables are getting messed up. I guess the HTTP request fails because of wrong value in variable "Header".

Can someone point out what is the mistake and how to keep one thread from not resetting the variable value of other thread?

Answer (score 0):

If there is really "lots" of processing in the Beanshell PreProcessor and you use lots of concurrent threads I would suggest considering switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as well-written Groovy code can be compiled into native Java bytecode while other scripting languages engines are re-evaluating the script each on each occurrence.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for more detailed explanation, benchmarks and scripting best practices.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the package. I did not handle the static variables properly. That kind of messed up the variables being overwritten.